# FilterAndCast Linq Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq

I have some places where I do something like this:

```
var listOfBaseClasses = new List<BaseClass>() { ... }
var things = listOfBaseClasses
    .Where(t => t is Thing)
    .Cast<Thing>()
    .ToList()
```

I realize this is a bit of a code smell, such is life when supporting someone else's code.

I would like to create an extension method to combine the Where and Cast extension methods. This is what I have so far..

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FilterAndCast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(TResult))
        {
            yield return (TResult)item;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

```
var things = listOfBaseClasses.OfType<Thing>.ToList()
```

Comment: Looks like I'm the only person who didn't know about OfType<T>. I'll pick yours since you were the first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
var things = listOfBaseClasses
.Where(t => t is Thing)
.Cast<Thing>()
.ToList()
```

You can  just use `OfType` method:

```
var things = listOfBaseClasses.OfType<Thing>().ToList();
```

Initially it uses the `is` operator and performing the `Cast` like this:

```
foreach (object obj in source) 
{
   if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will do the `Where` and `Cast` part for you.

```
var things = listOfBaseClasses.OfType<Thing>().ToList();
```

From [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OfType(IEnumerable) method returns only those elements in
>   source that can be cast to type TResult.